# Can I let the user buy from App store within my iOS app without going to App Store application at all?

Tags: iphone, ios, store

A button has a title "Buy Now", its action talks to App store and tell them that this user wants to pay for an app without launching the App store app at all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To buy what? If you want the user to buy an in-app purchase that's linked to your app, then yes (and take a look at Apple's in-app purchase programming guide for information on this).

If you mean to get the user to buy a different app from within your app, then you can use the `SKStoreProductViewController` ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011852)).